# Spark scala data type mismatch

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I try to find the case class matching each line of my json file. I have as error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot  resolve '`result`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast
ArrayType(StructType(StructField(hop,LongType,true), StructField(result,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(from,StringType,true), StructField(rtt,DoubleType,true), StructField(size,LongType,true), StructField(ttl,LongType,true)),true),true)),true)  ArrayType(StructType(StructField(result,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(rtt,DoubleType,true), StructField(ttl,IntegerType,true), StructField(from,StringType,true), StructField(size,IntegerType,true)),true),true), StructField(hop,IntegerType,true)),true);
```

and my case class are :

```
  case class Result(
result: Seq[Result1],
hop:    Int)

case class Result1(
rtt:  Double,
ttl:  Int,
from: String,
size: Int)
case class RootInterface(

dst_name: String,
from:     String,
prb_id:    BigInt,
msm_id:    BigInt,
timestamp: BigInt,
result:    Seq[Result])
```

The only difference is the order in the two  schemas, is it the problem lead to the exception? 
The result attribute in the exception is mapped by the case class Result.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What does your json file look like? What are the expected inputs and outputs? Where is the code you are running that gives you the error? Are you using jackson? If so, show it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, order is important! try this to compare schemas:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val jsonSchema1 = new StructType()
    .add("first", LongType)
    .add("second", LongType)

val jsonSchema2 = new StructType()
    .add("second", LongType)
    .add("first", LongType)

println(jsonSchema1 == jsonSchema2)
```

this should print *false*. Use the same to compare your schemas.